# Youtube video questions and Google Business map

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask Youtube video questions and Google Business map question in Stackoverflow ?

Comment: Are they about programming? If not, no you can't.

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to ask.

Comment: it's not about programming I've miss configured some app installation on Youtube connect Facebook and I've registered my client business place in google map.

Comment: It'd still be a better choice if you ask it first on google support forums.

Comment: Then it's not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not about programming, then it's off topic. However, questions about Youtube/Google Maps can go to  [Webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). Please read their [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the question is programming related you can.

Some other options:

- [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), for questions about... movies (read their help center carefully!);
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) for questions about the use of the applications.

Make sure the post is of high quality, since low-quality questions on such subject will get closed very fast.

Comment: But remember Movies and TV allow identification question but there quality matters.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Thanks. Updated my answer with a little extra warning.

Comment: *"Movies for movie identification"* - Keep in mind though that the asker doesn't talk about movie identification specifically and that site's scope is faaar larger than just identification. (not that either identification or anything else in the scope of that site would have anything to do with his question and arbitrary YouTube videos, though.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman On YouTube videos? Oh, there's much to ask (just nothing that would really fit on movies.se, I guess, including identification).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, identification of arbitrary web videos doesn't really fit either, I'm afraid. The simplest thing would just be to either not talk about any web-video identification, as that would be entirely misleading about the scope of that site.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your comment.